# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object on old php 5.1 code now running on php 5.4

Tags: php, fetch

I have this old code that was written around the time of PHP 5.1, I am trying to make it all work on a newer server running php5.4 however I am getting this error from the code below:

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

```
<?php
/**
* <b>Database Connection</b> class.
* @author Php Object Generator
* @version 3.0 / PHP5.1
* @see http://www.phpobjectgenerator.com/
* @copyright Free for personal & commercial use. (Offered under the BSD license)
*/
Class Database
{
private function Database()
{
    $databaseName = $GLOBALS['configuration']['db'];
    $driver = $GLOBALS['configuration']['pdoDriver'];
    $serverName = $GLOBALS['configuration']['host'];
    $databaseUser = $GLOBALS['configuration']['user'];
    $databasePassword = $GLOBALS['configuration']['pass'];
    $databasePort = $GLOBALS['configuration']['port'];


    $databaseName = 'bitbsoft_butlers';
    $driver = $GLOBALS['configuration']['pdoDriver'];
    $serverName = 'localhost';
    $databaseUser = 'bitbsoft_butlers';
    $databasePassword = 'Sherw00d123';
    $databasePort = '3306'; 



    if (!isset($this->connection))
    {
        $this->connection = new PDO($driver.':host='.$serverName.';port='.$databasePort.';dbname='.$databaseName, $databaseUser, $databasePassword);
        $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    if (!$this->connection)
    {
        throw new Exception('I cannot connect to the database. Please edit configuration.php with your database configuration.');
    } 
}

public static function Connect()
{
    static $database = null;
    if (!isset($database))
    {
        $database = new Database();
    }
    return $database->connection;
}

public static function Reader($query, $connection)
{
    try
    {
        $result = $connection->Query($query);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return $result;
}

public static function Read($result)
{
    try
    {
        return $result->fetch();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public static function NonQuery($query, $connection)
{
    try
    {
        $r = $connection->query($query);
        if ($r === false)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return $r->rowCount();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        return false;
    }

}

public static function Query($query, $connection)
{
    try
    {
        $i = 0;
        $r = $connection->query($query);
        foreach ($r as $row)
        {
            $i++;
        }
        return  $i;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public static function InsertOrUpdate($query, $connection)
{
    try
    {
        $r = $connection->query($query);
        return $connection->lastInsertId();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
}
?>
```

Now the error is being thrown by the line fetch() but I am confused as to what has changed from 5.1 to 5.4 that would cause this, would really appreciate any help on this.

Many thanks

Comment: As the only line where you catually call fetch is inside a function that does not get executed in the coude you showed us: mind to give a) the line in that the error occurs and b) the complete code?

Comment: "on a non-object" means $result isn't an object.  What is being passed to Read()?

Comment: sorry, bad cut and paste, here is the complete code. and the error inc line number is Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /home/bitbsoft/public_html/objects/class.database.php on line 68

Comment: The line on which you actually call `Read` is still missing (oh, and BTW, most coding conventions tell you to use lowercase names for functions, whiel uppercase names are used for classes)

Comment: there is a clientdisplay.php that is the page visited to produce the error, this calls the code above as per the error, I am therefore assuming the `read` comes from there. However it does have 13 includes for php files at the top! I am more than willing to give someone access to this software to see if its fixable and am happy to pay a fee if anyone is interested?

Comment: Use a proper IDE and it shouldn't be a probvlem to find all calls to a particular function ;)

Comment: Johannes that is great advice but I am hoping for a practical example of how I can correct this? would you be interested in looking at the code for me? willing to pay for your time.